# Retrieve the data using putExtra

Tags: android

I am doing admin page. I want to make changes to the data from server. The data already retrieved from server, but I do not know how to data can carry to the next activity(when i click Edit) using putExtra, because I use another java class to for retrieving the information. This is the sample of my table. 
Below is my java coding:

```
 public class assessment_table_edit extends AppCompatActivity {
        Toolbar toolbar;
        String data = "";
        TableLayout tlAssessment;
        TableRow tr;
        TextView stuID,totalmarks,marks,edit;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_assessment_table_edit);
            tlAssessment=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlAssessment_Edit);


            final Assessment_Information_GetData getdb=new Assessment_Information_GetData();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    data =getdb.getDataFromDB();
                    System.out.println(data);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ArrayList<Assessment_Information> users=parseJSON(data);
                            addData(users);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

        }

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.assessment_id:
                        Intent iChange=new Intent(assessment_table_edit.this,change_details.class);
//Having problem here
iChange.putExtra();
                        startActivity(iChange);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

Appreciate if some can enlighten me on how to use putExtra or other method to carry the data to another activity.

Comment: `putExtra` is not part of the Java API. Is it Android? If so, add the `android` tag so that people familiar with Android can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using,

```
Intent iChange = new Intent(assessment_table_edit.this,change_details.class);
iChange.putExtra("YOUR_KEY", "YOUR_VALUE");
startActivity(iChange);
```

You can get data using,

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your Object through Intent by using [putExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)) method

if you want to pass arraylist then you can use [putParcelableArrayListExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E))

```
  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);

ArrayList<Assessment_Information> testing = new ArrayList<Assessment_Information>();

i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra", testing);
startActivity(i);
}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Assessment_Information> testing = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra");
 }
}
```